# web2py: sqlite3.IntegrityError'>(foreign key constraint failed)

Tags: python, sqlite, web2py, referential-integrity

I know this is nth time this question is being asked in the forum,but please i need your help as i am not able to figure out what i am doing wrong.

Model

```
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',pool_size=1,check_reserved=['all'])
auth = Auth(db)
service = Service()
plugins = PluginManager()
auth.define_tables(migrate=False)
auth.define_tables(username=False, signature=False)

db.define_table('nsksystem',
            Field('email_id', db.auth_user,length=512, label = 'Email ID'),
            Field('nskname', length=128, default='', label = 'Machine Name'),
            Field('nskpassword', 'password', length=512,readable=False, label='Machine Password'),
            Field('confirmnskpassword', 'password', length=512,readable=False, label='Confirm Machine Password'),
            Field('nreleaseid',length=128, default='',label = 'Release'),
            Field('isCordinator','boolean',default='', label = 'Is Co-ordinator'))

db.nsksystem.email_id.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message=auth.messages.is_empty)
db.nsksystem.email_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db,'auth_user.email','%(email)s')
db.nsksystem.nreleaseid.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message=auth.messages.is_empty)
db.nsksystem.nskname.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message=auth.messages.is_empty)
db.nsksystem.confirmnskpassword.requires = IS_EXPR('value==%s' % repr(request.vars.get('nskpassword', None)),error_message='Passwords do not match')
db.nsksystem.isCordinator.requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.nsksystem.nreleaseid == request.vars.nreleaseid), 'nsksystem.isCordinator', error_message='Co-ordinator Already exist for specified release')
```

Controller

```
def uregistration():
    form=SQLFORM(db.auth_user)
        if form.process().accepted:
            response.flash = 'User is registered. Redirecting to machine registration'
            redirect(URL('mregistration'))
        elif form.errors:
            response.flash = 'Form has errors'
        else:
            response.flash = 'Please fill out the form'
        return dict(form=form)
def mregistration():
        form=SQLFORM(db.nsksystem)
            if form.process().accepted:
                response.flash = 'Machine is registered to user. Please go to Login page.'
                redirect(URL('index'))
            elif form.errors:
                response.flash = 'Form has errors'
            else:
                response.flash = 'Please fill out the form'
                return dict(form=form)
```

After i did a successful registration I was directed to Machine registration URL. I had to select email id from the list of a drop down. This email ID i had given while registration.
After i submit i get this error.

Traceback

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gluon/restricted.py", line 224, in restricted
  File "C:/web2py/applications/click/controllers/default.py", line 63, in <module>
  File "gluon/globals.py", line 393, in <lambda>
  File "C:/web2py/applications/click/controllers/default.py", line 30, in mregistration
    if form.process().accepted:
  File "gluon/html.py", line 2303, in process
  File "gluon/html.py", line 2240, in validate
  File "gluon/sqlhtml.py", line 1677, in accepts
  File "gluon/dal/objects.py", line 724, in insert
  File "gluon/dal/adapters/base.py", line 715, in insert
IntegrityError: foreign key constraint failed

Error snapshot
  <class 'sqlite3.IntegrityError'>(foreign key constraint failed)

 Function argument list


  (self=<gluon.dal.adapters.sqlite.SQLiteAdapter object>, 
  table=<Table nsksystem   (id,email_id,nskname,nskpassword,confirmnskpassword,nreleaseid,isCordinator)>,
   fields=[(<gluon.dal.objects.Field object>, '1234'), 
  (<gluon.dal.objects.Field object>, 'yennae.ind.codefactory.com'), 
  (<gluon.dal.objects.Field object>, 0), 
  (<gluon.dal.objects.Field object>, True), 
  (<gluon.dal.objects.Field object>, 'AAA'), 
  (<gluon.dal.objects.Field object>, '1234')])
```

And moreover i dont see my email id being displayed in the Function argument list, that is displayed in the ticket.
 I cant turn the constraint off as it is a requirement.

And next thing even though i flush my db.auth_user , 10 records getadded automatically. How can i stop this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.nsksystem.email_id` is defined as a reference to the `db.auth_user` table, which means it must store a record ID from `db.auth_user` (which is an integer), not an email address. So, the validator you have defined is incorrect:

```
db.nsksystem.email_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'auth_user.email', '%(email)s')
```

It should instead be:

```
db.nsksystem.email_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'auth_user.id', '%(email)s')
```

In fact, there is no reason to explicitly define that validator, as it is the default validator for a reference field. (Note, the HTML select widget will display a list of email addresses, but the actual value submitted and stored will be the `auth_user` record ID associated with the email address.)

A couple other problems:

Don't call `auth.define_tables()` twice (and don't call it with `migrate=False` unless the tables have already been defined as you need them).

Don't set the `requires` attribute of a field twice, as the second one will simply overwrite the first. Also, there is no need to set an `IS_NOT_EMPTY` validator if there is also an `IS_IN_DB` validator, as the latter does not allow empty values anyway.

Comment: I do have one question but.. how to stop auth_user database being autopopulate with user info.. for example ...before even i add records to auth_user db.. it has got 10 records.. even though i delete those,, 10 more gets added automatically...

Comment: You must have some code somewhere that adds 10 random records if the table is empty -- probably somewhere in a model file.